# Task 'default' is not in your gulpfile

Tags: gulp, laravel-elixir, gulp-uglify

I have tried the NPM install and removed the node_modules folder however I am still getting the error when I run gulp etc

Have I missed something out of my file?

```
var gulp   = require('gulp');
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');


    /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Elixir Asset Management
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
     */


    /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Elixir JS Asset Management
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
     */

     elixir.extend('uglify', function(){

        gulp.task('uglify', function(){

            gulp.src('public/admin/js/*.js')
                .pipe(uglify())
                .pipe(ext('-min.js'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('public/admin/js'));
        });
            return this.queueTask('uglify');
     });
```

Comment: I'm assuming your package.json specifies `gulp` in the `start` script, but it looks like you have no default gulp task specified.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy my package.json is like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/thtiy5118ohp5h6/Screenshot%202016-04-19%2007.01.56.png?dl=0

Comment: That's the wrong section of the file. What's under "scripts"?

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy Thats my whole file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel Elixir the default tasks are:

```
gulp watch
gulp build
```

Give that a try. Also make sure your node_modules folder contains the laravel-elixir folder.

Comment: Thanks but Ib get the same error - diff "value" with every single one

Comment: I'll quote Jeffrey Way here: "You might have had a faulty install. Try deleting your node_modules directory, and doing npm install again."

Answer (score 2):

Like some people say in the comments, you don't have a task in gulp called "default". You have 2 options:

- Create a 'default' task:

  ```
  var gulp   = require('gulp');
  var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
  var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');


  /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Elixir Asset Management
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   */


  /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Elixir JS Asset Management
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   */

  elixir.extend('uglify', function(){

      gulp.task('uglify', function(){

          gulp.src('public/admin/js/*.js')
              .pipe(uglify())
              .pipe(ext('-min.js'))
              .pipe(gulp.dest('public/admin/js'));
      });
  return this.queueTask('uglify');
  });

  elixir.extend('default', function(){

      gulp.task('default', function(){
          //Your code here!
      });
  return this.queueTask('default');
  });
  ```
- Call Gulp with "gulp uglify" instead of just "gulp" to run the task that you already have.

I do not have knowlege about Laravel so I hope this answer serves you.

Comment: What @franmartosr said, you need to run that specific gulp task e.g "gulp uglify" instead of just gulp which will look for

gulp.task('default', function() {

});